# Jmeter Corelation

Tags: jmeter, single-sign-on

I'm not able to find value for "Original request" and "flowToken"  from the responses of last requests, as shown in body data. Can you please help me out to how to find above-mentioned dynamic values?

This is the current error I am experiencing
[image]

Comment: I want to login as Microsoft SSO  client and I'm not able find dynamic values those are required to corelate....can anyone please help me out to do the same or anyone can share Sample script for login as microsoft SSO user!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case it's not in the response **body**, it might be a part of URL where you're being [redirected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) or comes as a [response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Response_header)

Try performing your login in browser having the Network tab of the [developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Developer_Tools) active and recording the requests, then export the requests and responses as [HAR file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format)) (which is normal [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) under the hood) and search for these request parameters to detect the request where they appear first.

You might also want to try out [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285437-Recording-Your-Session) which is capable of exporting recorded requests in "Smart JMX" mode with automatic detection and correlation of dynamic parameters

Comment: yes, I have tried to find it out from the response body and response header but it doesn't work